# Listbox text not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox that the text is not updating when I change the underlying objects properties:

```
ClassA testObj = new ClassA(){name="myname"};

ListBox1.items.Add(testObj);

Class ClassA
{
public string name {get;set;}
public override string ToString()
 {
  return name;
 }
}
```

so if I update the ClassA.name property the Listbox does not update. I have tried to call the listboxes refresh() method.

Comment: ListBox doesn't have an Add() method.  There's no sign in your snippet of you assigning the ClassA.name property.  Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: thanks for comments Hans...I did make the edits as you suggested.

Comment: You are still posting code that cannot compile, the capitalization is all wrong.  The point of using snippets is to demonstrate *real* code that doesn't work properly, you copy-paste it from your program into the snippet.  Right now you just posted code that you *think* should work.  I think so too, but it doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the item in the list with a new reference:

```
ClassA item = (ClassA)listBox1.Items[0];
item.name = "New Item";
listBox1.Items[0] = item;
```

Unfortunately, a bad side effect of this is it fires the `SelectedIndexChanged` event multiple times, so you would need to remove the handler and add it back in or set a flag to work around that behavior.

Or just have your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have your list use a `BindingList<ClassA>` as it's `DataSource`, then any changes to an item's property would automatically update the ListBox.

Comment: I agree the second option with using INotifyPropertyChanged is the way to go. [How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your class "ClassA" should inherit an interface called "INumerable"